# Webiopi (Raspberry pi) with sql or sqlite

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, raspberry-pi, webiopi

I've got some problem with making database work with webiopi. I'm already import sqlite3 and change folder permission but when I'm run webiopi nothing had been create. However, other function after `f.write('This is a test\n')` every process work normally and repeat the loop. Hope you can help me?

```
def loop():
    db = sqlite3.connect('schedule.db')
    db.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schedule')
    db.execute('CREATE TABLE schedule (hour int, minute int, second int, status text)')
    db.execute('INSERT INTO schedule (hour,minute,second,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',(sche.get('hour'),sche.get('minute'),sche.get('second'),"yes"))
    db.commit()
    f = open('workfile', 'w')
    f.write('This is a test\n')
    loop1=1
    while ((now.minute >= minute_ON) and (now.minute < minute_OFF) and (loop1<stepping)):
        step()
        loop1=loop1+1
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean nothing had been create? The file workfile or the schedule.db file?

Comment: Both of them. The step() which I'm use to control stepping motor work fine so I'm really confuse why database or even text file haven't create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For database, you may use cursor and conn for better. See [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for more.

For file, you may `close()` it when you don't use it for write data.
The code below may helps:

```
def loop():
    db = sqlite3.connect('schedule.db')
    cur = db.cursor() # create a cursor
    cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schedule')
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE schedule (hour int, minute int, second int, status text)')
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO schedule (hour,minute,second,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',(sche.get('hour'),sche.get('minute'),sche.get('second'),"yes"))
    db.commit()

    cur.close() # close cursor
    db.close() # close connection to sqlite3

    f = open('workfile', 'w')
    f.write('This is a test\n')
    f.close() # close file to write data

    loop1=1
    while ((now.minute >= minute_ON) and (now.minute < minute_OFF) and (loop1<stepping)):
        step()
        loop1=loop1+1
```

Comment: Thank you! close() database solve my entire problem.